# How to detect tornado Env variables

Tags: python, mysql, nginx, tornado

Currently i have built an app using tornado and mysql in nginx server. My question is i have the mysql database credentials configured according to localhost. Now when i push the code to server how can we dynamically set the server mysql configuration.

Localhost

```
# Configuration settings
    self.__HOST__     = "localhost"
    self.__USER__     = "root"
    self.__PASSWORD__ = "demo"
    self.__DB__       = "demo_db"
```

Is there any way to detect if its localhost or production server in tornado python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use the [tornado.options module](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html) and you create two different configuration files, something like *production.conf* and *development.conf*. In your main function, you do check if development.conf exists and read it, if not use *production.conf*. Now, make sure you only push *production.conf* to your deployment server and you'd have a clean setup that distinguishes between production and development settings.

Comment: Thank you Bernhard :) I made a very stupid tweak. Just used os modules to check if its a desktop or production.